# Android database field in row update working only once

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-update

I want to change a single column inside a row. I'm trying to update the value inside "remindOnDate" field to "reminder" in the "tasks" table.
I tried a few things but they all work only when remindOnDate is null. Once it has a value stored in it, update won't work on it. I don't know why. What am I doing wrong? If the statement is wrong then it shouldn't work even when remindOnDate is null.

I tried this:

```
ContentValues editTask = new ContentValues();
editTask.put("remindOnDate", reminder);
database.update("tasks", editTask, "_id = ?", new String[]{id+""});
```

I also tried the following instead of the last  line:

```
database.update("tasks", editTask, "_id = " + id, null);
```

Here is another thing I tried:

```
String createQuery = "UPDATE tasks SET remindOnDate = '" + reminder + "' WHERE _id = " + id + ";";
database.execSQL(createQuery);
```

Comment: Yes I'm trying to update, thank you for the edit. But I still need the WHERE clause.

Comment: So, you are passing the **wrong id** to the query. **That id** doesn't exist in your table. `WILD GUESS`: You are passing the position of a selected ListView item as the id for your WHERE clause.

Comment: check the value of "reminder" string before you try updating. It should be the issue

Comment: It was the id. I was using the id from the wrong activity. Thanks a lot!